# Error in Exporting Contacts Using Address Book Framework iOS 9?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, ios9

Contacts are not getting added in the address book. Error Saving person to AddressBook in iOS 9 but working in iOS 6. When i add the contact then the if block is executed with Log Error Saving person to AddressBook.

```
-(void)addContactToPhoneBook{

ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *peoplePicker=[[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
addressBook = [peoplePicker addressBook];

// create person record
person = ABPersonCreate();

cfError = nil;


if (firstName) {
    ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty, (__bridge CFTypeRef)(firstName) , nil);
}

if (jobTitle) {
    ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonJobTitleProperty,(__bridge CFTypeRef)(jobTitle), nil);
}

if (personEmail)
{
    ABMutableMultiValueRef emailMultiValue = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiStringPropertyType);
    ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(emailMultiValue, (__bridge CFStringRef) personEmail, kABWorkLabel, NULL);
    ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty, emailMultiValue, nil);
    CFRelease(emailMultiValue);
}

if (phoneNo)
{
    ABMutableMultiValueRef phoneNumberMultiValue = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiStringPropertyType);
    NSArray *venuePhoneNumbers = [phoneNo componentsSeparatedByString:@" or "];
    for (NSString *venuePhoneNumberString in venuePhoneNumbers)
        ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(phoneNumberMultiValue, (__bridge CFStringRef) venuePhoneNumberString, kABPersonPhoneMainLabel, NULL);
    ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty, phoneNumberMultiValue, nil);
    CFRelease(phoneNumberMultiValue);
}

// add address

ABMutableMultiValueRef multiAddress = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiDictionaryPropertyType);
NSMutableDictionary *addressDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(multiAddress, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef) addressDictionary, kABWorkLabel, NULL);
ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonAddressProperty, multiAddress, NULL);
CFRelease(multiAddress);


//Add person Object to addressbook Object.
ABAddressBookAddRecord(addressBook, person, &cfError);

if (ABAddressBookSave(addressBook, nil))
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Success" message:@"Contact added sucessfully" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
    NSLog(@"\nPerson Saved successfuly");
} else
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Failed" message:@"Failed to add contact" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
    NSLog(@"\n Error Saving person to AddressBook");
}  
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    arrContactName = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    arrPhoneNumber = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    arrAddContact = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

}
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    ABAddressBookRef addressBookRef = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);

    if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined)
    {
        ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBookRef, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
            if (granted) {
                [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
            } else {
                [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
            }
        });
    }
    else if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusAuthorized)
    {
        [self getAllContacts];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Unable to Access!" message:@"Grant us access now! Change privacy setting in settings app." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Not now" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark - Get All Contacts
-(void)getAllContacts
{
    CFErrorRef error = NULL;
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, &error);

    if (addressBook != nil)
    {
        NSArray *allContacts = (__bridge_transfer NSArray    *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);

        NSUInteger i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < [allContacts count]; i++)
        {
            ABRecordRef contactPerson = (__bridge ABRecordRef)allContacts[i];
            NSString *firstName = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(contactPerson, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
            NSString *lastName =  (__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(contactPerson, kABPersonLastNameProperty);
            if (lastName == nil) {
                strLastname = @"";
            }
            else
                strLastname = lastName;

            NSString *fullName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", firstName, strLastname];
            NSString *phone=nil;
            ABMultiValueRef phoneNumbers = ABRecordCopyValue(contactPerson,                                                                                kABPersonPhoneProperty);
            if (ABMultiValueGetCount(phoneNumbers) > 0) {
                phone = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)
                ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneNumbers, 0);
            } else {
                phone = @"[None]";
            }
            [arrContactName addObject:fullName];
            [arrPhoneNumber addObject:phone];
            NSLog(@"Full Name =%@",fullName);
            NSLog(@"Phone Number =%@",phone);
        }
        CFRelease(addressBook);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please Review the question again.